# regex negative look-ahead javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

My code reads a line from a file and replaces numbers of length 3 to 18 digits.

The thing is I don't want to match numbers that follow the string `DOM:`  (white space after colon).

For example:

> **match:** tttt 23456789 dkdkd
>
> **match:** 6783456789 dkdkd DOM:
>
> **no match:** DOM: 23456789 dkdkd
>
> **no match:** dhdhd DOM: 23456789 dkdkd
>
> **no match:** DOM: 2789 dkdkd DOM: 34567896

I have tried using negative look-ahead: `.*(?!DOM: )[0-9]{3,18}`

But it doesn't work, please help.

Comment: You are looking for negative look-behind, which JS does not yet have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't since the lookbehind isn't available in javascript.

The workaround is to use a function as replacement with the replace method:

```
yourstr = yourstr.replace(/\b(DOM: )?\d{3,18}\b/g, function (m, g) {
    return g ? m : 'what you want'; });
```

Comment: Thanks, I will do something similar to what you have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

A usual approach to mimick a lookbehind where a lookahead is not necessary (and here, a lookahead is not used), is through reversal. You reverse both the input string, the regex pattern where you can thus use a *lookahead* instead of a lookbehind, and then the results:

```js
function revStr(str) {
    return str.split('').reverse().join('');
}

var s = ["tttt 23456789 dkdkd", "6783456789 dkdkd DOM:",
 "DOM: 23456789 dkdkd", "dhdhd DOM: 23456789 dkdkd", "DOM: 2789 dkdkd DOM: 34567896"];
var rex = /\b[0-9]{3,18}\b(?!\s*:MOD\b)/g;  // Regex for matching reversed numbers 
var results = [];                          // Array for results
s.forEach(function(t) {                    // Test each string
     m = revStr(t).match(rex);             // Collect all matches
     if (m) {                              // If we have a match
         m.forEach(function(h) { 
            results.push(revStr(h));       // Reverse each match value and add
         });
     }
  }
);
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(results, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your response